# Magento 2 - Create order programmatically without payment

Tags: magento2, orders, payment-methods

I'm going to create an order programmatically without a payment. But it requires to set a valid payment method when I run the following code. Is there any way to skip it?

```
    $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create();
    $quote->setStore($store);
    $quote->setCurrency($store->getCurrentCurrency()->getDataModel());
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer->getDataModel());
    $quote->addProduct($product);
    $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); 
    $quote->save();
    $order = $this->_quoteManagement->submit($quote);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, in Magento 2.0.2 - 2.1 version, we cannot create an order without any payment methods.

Magento sets payment for order: **vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php**

```
$order->setPayment($this->quotePaymentToOrderPayment->convert($quote->getPayment()));
```

Convert payment from quote object:

**vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Payment/ToOrderPayment.php**

```
 $orderPayment->setAdditionalInformation(
            array_merge(
                $object->getAdditionalInformation(),
                [Substitution::INFO_KEY_TITLE => $object->getMethodInstance()->getTitle()]
            )
        );
```

And then getting method instance:

**vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Info.php**

```
  public function getMethodInstance()
  {
        if (!$this->hasMethodInstance()) {
            if (!$this->getMethod()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('The payment method you requested is not available.')
                );
            }

            try {
                $instance = $this->_paymentData->getMethodInstance($this->getMethod());
            } catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
                $instance = $this->_paymentData->getMethodInstance(Method\Substitution::CODE);
            }

            $instance->setInfoInstance($this);
            $this->setMethodInstance($instance);
        }

        return $this->_getData('method_instance');
  }
```

In cases, Magento will check the available payment methods. If it doesn't have any payment methods, it will throw exceptions.

**A Substitution payment method is assigned if non-existing payments**: `vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/Substitution.php`

Comment: Thanks @khoa, is there a payment method called "free"? I try it but still no hope

Comment: what is the code for Cash on Delivery?

Comment: Cash On Delivery - `cod`

Comment: How can I know the code for different payment method? Can i check it in database?

Comment: You can use `getPaymentMethodList` in `vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php`. You can also see some offline payments: `vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/Model`. For example: Bank Tranfer: `\Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Banktransfer::PAYMENT_METHOD_BANKTRANSFER_CODE`

Comment: We have enabled paypal express checkout as the only payment method. But  when I set `$quote->setPaymentMethod('wps_express')`, it returns `The requested Payment Method is not available.`. Do you know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43874/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-zzpaul).

Comment: To others who reference this later: the above answers are wrong or else out of date. There is a "free" method (Zero Subtotal Checkout).

Comment: @ScottSB Yes, you're right! Thanks! However, my answer may not be wrong. My comment was wrong. I have just deleted it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I said "answers" when I meant "comments."

Answer (score 1):

The other answer by Khoa TruongDinh is correct that Magento does require you to set a payment method, but in most similar cases the goal is simply to create an order without payment details: not specifically without a payment method at all.

In order to avoid specifying payment details, there are two generic built-in payment methods that you can use to fulfill Magento's requirement:

- Zero Subtotal Payment: `'free'`
- Check/Money Order: `'checkmo'`

The Zero Subtotal Payment requires a subtotal of zero (surprise, surprise), while the Check/Money Order method can be used with any subtotal. Both can be renamed to appear as other names through the Magento admin configuration.

To set one of these methods on a quote, inject `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\PaymentFactory` into your class, set it to `$this->paymentFactory` in your constructor, and then do the following (replacing "[method code]" with either `'free'` or `'checkmo'` as desired):

```
$payment = $this->paymentFactory->create();
$payment->setMethod([method code]);
$quote->setPayment($payment);
```

The issue with the code in the original question was that it attempts to use a non-existent method (`setPaymentMethod`) to set the payment code directly on the quote. Instead, you must create a `Payment` object as above.

Comment: There is another offline payment: Bank Transfer: `vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/Model/Banktransfer.php`.

Comment: quote.setPaymentMethod(), then what it means, Can you tell me

Comment: @Sri Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you try rephrasing it?

Comment: How Do I unset the selected payment method using the below code quote.setPaymentMethod(). Please refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229212/how-to-unset-the-selected-payment-method-in-magento-2

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean. Are you trying to unset it in the front-end Knockout model or in the server-side PHP/database model? The other question you linked (and the one it links to) are about front-end refreshes, but the original question I answered here was about server-side code.

Comment: Another approach would be `$payment = $quote->getPayment(); if (!$payment->getId()) { $payment->setMethod('[METHOD_CODE]'); }`
This way you do not need to inject the PaymentFactory as `$quote->getPayment()` creates a new Payment object if none is set.