# How to unset the selected payment method in magento 2

Tags: payment-methods, payment, magento2.2.2

I have created custom icon in checkout page, after clicking that icon, I have refreshed the payment section using below link

[Magento 2: How to refresh payment method on some condition](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/magento-2-how-to-refresh-payment-method-on-some-condition?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But before refreshing, I wish to unset the selected payment method, Please provide me a solution

Comment: you can try this code. quote.setPaymentMethod(NULL).

Comment: I have tried, it unsets  the selected payment method for a second, then again sets the selected payment method with in a secod.